# Unable to remove SSL Security error inside a Python virtualenv with Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, ssl, virtualenv

I have an odd problem that I am hoping to get help with.  My Python code uses the Requests module over HTTPS to get JSON information over the Internet. Everything works smoothly in the non-virtenv Python instance although I had to install OpenSSL/PyOpenSSL as discussed in [this link](https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html) to remove an insecure platform notification.

Now as part of playing with Flask, I have created a Virtual Environment.  Unfortunately, the SSL error is back and every method listed in the link above does not work.  Here is the error message:

> /home/pi/.virtualenvs/flasktest1/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:90:
>   InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available.
>   This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause
>   certain SSL connections to fail. For more information, see
>   https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.
>   InsecurePlatformWarning

The most obvious solution is to install OpenSSL/PyOpenSSL inside the virtenv, but unfortunately the installation fails with the error listed below.

> Command "/home/pi/.virtualenvs/flasktest1/bin/python -c "import
>   setuptools,
>   tokenize;**file**='/tmp/pip-build-6D2PfU/cffi/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(**file**).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), **file**,
>   'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-o43kpB-record/install-record.txt
>   --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/pi/.virtualenvs/flasktest1/include/site/python2.7/cffi" failed
>   with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-6D2PfU/cffi

I am now at a loss how to fix this.  To be clear, this app is being developed behind a firewall and is for experimentation purposes only and will not be publicly accessible.  However, this error is causing difficulties and I just want to make it stop.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 4):

For me (OS X 10.10), a `pip install pyopenssl ndg-httpsclient pyasn1` fixed the issue.