# Unable to install packages using pip in virtualenv

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip

I am trying to install various python packages using pip in my virtual environment but couldn't install. If I try to install the same package not in virtual environment then it gets installed. Every time I get the different errors. I am pasting one of the errors below which I got while installing scrapy.

> Command "/home/namita/venv/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;**file**='/tmp/pip-build-AHL0d8/cffi/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(**file**).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), **file**, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-Dk98DU-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/namita/venv/include/site/python2.7/cffi" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-AHL0d8/cffi

And I also get below mentioned warning:

> /home/namita/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/*vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl*.py:90: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.
>     InsecurePlatformWarning

I tried visiting https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning but was not satisfied.

Answer (score 1):

> I tried visiting
>   https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning
>   but was not satisfied.

The solution is quite clear :

> If you encounter this warning, it is strongly recommended you upgrade
>   to a newer Python version, or that you use pyOpenSSL as described in
>   the OpenSSL / PyOpenSSL section.

If you do not want to upgrade your Python version (>2.7.9), install the following packages :

```
$ pip install pyopenssl ndg-httpsclient pyasn1
```

It has been proven to work for other similar issues :

- [InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29134512/insecureplatformwarning-a-true-sslcontext-object-is-not-available-this-prevent)
- [Unable to remove SSL Security error inside a Python virtualenv with Raspberry Pi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29989632/unable-to-remove-ssl-security-error-inside-a-python-virtualenv-with-raspberry-pi)
- [SSL InsecurePlatform error when using Requests package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29099404/ssl-insecureplatform-error-when-using-requests-package)

Comment: Thank you @georgesl. I did not want to upgrade python version. That warning is not coming now. And some packages have installed now. But again for certain packages, I am getting this error  " Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-jly38Q/nltk "

Answer (score 0):

From a fresh installation of 14.04, I had to install python-dev, libffi-dev, libssl-dev, libxml2-dev, and libxslt1-dev packages. Once those were installed, pip install scrapy worked fine.

```
sudo apt-get install python-dev libffi-dev libssl-dev libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev
pip install scrapy
```